# scanning a matrix diagonally for the largest product of four adjacent numbers along a diagonal line and stating it's starting postion

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multiplication

Alright so i have a 20x20 grid that i want to scan diagonally for the largest product of four adjacent numbers. now it keeps giving me the error indices are outside of boundaries while if my loop conditions are correct it should not exceed the boundaries.here is my theory;columns are checked one by one while the rows increment by 4 so that i will keep getting exactly 4 values along a diagonal line at a time. it notifies my that the error is in formula for the diagonal scanning but i don't understand why. please keep in mind i am not scanning the main diagonals(left or right) i am trying to scan the whole grid diagonally and i am a total beginner at programming. so if anyone may please point out the error and explain it i would be very grateful.

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 16; c +=4)
        {
            for (int z = 0; c <= 16; z ++)
            {
                int productdiagonally = (matrix [c, z] * matrix [c+ 1 , z + 1] * matrix [c + 2, z + 2] * matrix [c + 3, z + 3]);

                if (productdiagonally > largestproductdiagonally)
                {
                    largestproductdiagonally = productdiagonally;

                    rowmaxdiagonally = c;

                    colmaxdiagonally = z;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used c instead of z in your inner loop's exit condition.

You need:

```
for (int z = 0; z <= 16; z ++)
```

Otherwise the loop will never terminate, and will run off into accessing array elements that are out of bounds.

Comment: Wow that was simple , can't believe i missed that

Comment: Only if it relates directly to this question and answer. Otherwise, it's best to post it as new question to make sure it is seen by a wider audience!

Comment: alright i'll post a new question and hope you help there aswell :D